# Getting "Worker crashed" errors in Octez 9.4

Tags: node

Any idea why my `tezos-node` isn't syncing, and what the `Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]` errors mean?

`tezos-node` is logging a bunch of errors like the following and doesn't appear to be syncing.
I'm running Octez 9.4 with version string `706457dc (2021-07-02 23:42:56 +0200) (9.4)`.

It was running fine a few hours ago, then I hard-reset my machine and this issue appeared.

Thanks!

```
Jul 19 01:06:45.421 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Jul 19 01:06:45.422 - validator.peer: Failed to checkout the context with hash CoUjiWvRJWha
Jul 19 01:06:45.422 - validator.chain: Disconnection of idsQA1uSJAQEMMt5owNyWtpFpMG7pJ
Jul 19 01:06:47.157 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: fetching branch of about 49 blocks from peer idrh53JmnynhUM8a67mePAXAVqTeYt
Jul 19 01:06:47.157 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   in 24 steps
Jul 19 01:06:47.170 - validator.block: validation of block BMWBZqRYcjhmD1jUZfbDuagchuW7wuk815MD6GdriwP3Xp5KMRr failed
Jul 19 01:06:47.170 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2021-07-19T01:06:47.160-00:00, treated in 3.180us, completed in 9.403ms ,
Jul 19 01:06:47.170 - validator.block: Failed to checkout the context with hash CoUjiWvRJWha
Jul 19 01:06:47.170 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers:
Jul 19 01:06:47.170 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Failed to checkout the context with hash CoUjiWvRJWha
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.peer: New branch BLQDnZfHqzcRedViMGXE6SnkHxgSaAYqRLmBVY2ZyN97TYXn4k7, locator length 9381
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.peer:  Request pushed on 2021-07-19T01:06:47.156-00:00, treated in 44.409us, completed in 14.380ms ,
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.peer: Failed to checkout the context with hash CoUjiWvRJWha
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.peer: Failed to checkout the context with hash CoUjiWvRJWha
Jul 19 01:06:47.171 - validator.chain: Disconnection of idrh53JmnynhUM8a67mePAXAVqTeYt
Jul 19 01:06:49.454 - validator.chain: Disconnection of idthkLKF3oLrrW9Wq9A71onw594H2s
```

EDIT: I ran disk consistency checks by doing `sudo touch /forcefsck`, but that didn't seem to have any effect. So I'm guessing it's not a disk thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database powering tezos is extremely susceptible to crashes and corruption. Trash your datadir and import a fresh snapshot.

Comment: Restoring from a fresh snapshot is what finally fixed it 