# Sporadic missing endorsements and worker crashed

Tags: node, baking, missed-endorsement

I'm a little baker almost from the start of Tezos, and i'm quite annoyed because i've got some missing endorsements, and if i compare to big bakers, they 've got also some missing endorsements, but comparatively, it's a lot less.

So i've got some question, is it normal first ? and how can I stabilize my node if not ?

In addition, my node crash hardly every ~25 days, i can't recover and i have to reimport a snapshot from https://mainnet.xtz-shots.io/full. The error message is something like Worker crashed [node_peer_validator] like in this [stackexchange](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3602/getting-worker-crashed-errors-in-octez-9-4).

my node run on a virtual machine in proxmox environment, with sufficient RAM/SSD/CPU, as you can see in my grafana graph :
[image: grafana]

From 11/12 i've try to allocate 16Gb of RAM, but results are the same, my tzkt.io array of endorsements is always randomly red :(

[image: tzkt array]

I'm tired to manage this kind of node which isn't stable at all.My configuration is :a proxmox VM with 2 CPU, 16GB RAM, 300G SSD(Virtio)latest docker image v11.0 with the usage of mainnet.sh some monitoring scripts which request only

- **localhost:8732/network/connections**
- **localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/head**
- **localhost:8732/chains/main/is_bootstrapped**

the mainnet.sh is modified to connect only fondation nodes in private mode with the following command :

```
command: tezos-node --rpc-addr localhost:8732 --private-mode --no-bootstrap-peers --connections=20 --bootstrap-threshold=1 --peer=dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732 --peer=franodes.tzbeta.net:9732 --peer=sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732 --peer=nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732 --peer=pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732 --net-addr :$port $@
```

Is someone have any clues to stop theses missing endorsements and crashs please ?

Comment: you should specify what version of tezos binaries you running on. Also, it would be helpful to show the logs prior to a crash as that could be due to many reasons.